# VBA userform to check file exists in selected folder

Tags: excel, vba

We copy PDF's from a master folder into a designated project folder, I have created user form which allows the user to check the existence of the PDF file based on the value in row 'B'

I have successfully created a script which will allow me to check the existence of the PDF in the master folder, but this is by providing the folder location in the code. The second folder I need to check will change depending on the location of the project hence why I have the user form to select the folder location

```
Private Sub slctfldrcmd_Click()
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        '.InitialFileName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename()

        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode

        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    choosefldrtb.Value = sItem

    Set fldr = Nothing
End Sub


Private Sub runcmd_Click()
    'ActiveSheet.Columns("H:K").ClearContents

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim R As Range

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    For Each R In Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
        If R <> vbNullString Then ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Delete       
    Next R

    For Each R In Range("G2:G" & Cells(Rows.Count, "G").End(xlUp).Row)
        If R <> vbNullString Then Columns("J").ClearContents     
    Next R

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Dim c As Range

        For Each c In Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
            If c <> vbNullString Then
                c.Offset(0, 8).Value = "=IF(FileExists4(RC[-8]), ""ok"", ""missing"")"
            End If
        Next c
    Next ws

    'Call Draw_Clean 
    'Call Hyperlinks2

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With

    'MsgBox "PDF's Checked"          
    MsgBox "Drawings in " & choosefldrtb.Value & "  Checked"        
End Sub


Function FileExists4(sFile As String)     
    sPath = FldrChkuserform.choosefldrtb.Value & "\" & sFile & ".PDF"
    FileExists4 = Dir(sPath) <> ""
End Function
```

At the moment everything is working apart from the return value in column 'J' which should state "ok" or "missing" All that happens is "#NAME?" I think it has something to do with the value in the text box not transferring through to the 'FileExists4' function?

Comment: hi. whats the value of RC[-8] ?

Comment: the function will check the existence of a file with the same value as column B and return either 'ok' or 'missing' in column J. RC[-8] is getting it to look 8 cells to the right

Comment: do u have the FileExists4 function in a module ?

Comment: no, but it isn't in a module in the working code

Comment: i think that FileExist4 must be in a module to be available to excel

Comment: Thanks, that has fixed it

Comment: nice. dont forguet to mark que answer has good. thanks